# recursively build a tree from an array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

From a `.csv` file I need to build a tree structure using three columns below.
Column **state** should be the parent node, **id** is a child node of **state** and **ndi** is a child of **id** node.
Currently my program can read the `.csv` file and store it in a two dimensional array.

Here is my code: [Link to .csv file](http://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/plm/Cigar.csv)

```
<body>
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>

<script>
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; 


    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {

      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {

          var string = e.target.result;
          console.log(string);

          var array1=string.split("\n");
          alert(array1.length)
          var array2 = new Array();


          for(var i=0; i< array1.length; i++){
            array2[i] = array1[i].split(",");
          }
          //completed upto saving as 2D array

        };
      })(f);

      reader.readAsText(f);

      }
    }
  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

I want to build a tree structure out of it.

Comment: Is `id` the first column of the csv file? The second `for` is reading a whole line per loop?

Comment: Have you made any code up until now that actually does what you asked?

Comment: `id` is the first column

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, replace your second `for` with the code below:

```
// We cannot define our own keys for Javascript arrays, so we are using Object
var result     = new Object(); 
var salesIndex = 8;
var idIndex    = 0;
var ndiIndex   = 7;

for(var i=0; i< array1.length; i++){
    // array containing all line's columns
    var columns = array1[i].split(",");

    // especific columns that is of our interest
    var rowSale = columns[salesIndex];
    var rowId   = columns[idIndex];
    var rowNdi  = columns[ndiIndex];

    // If sale key doesn't exists in the array, add it
    if (!(rowSale in columns)) {
        result.rowSale.rowId = new Array();
        result.rowSale.rowId.push(rowNdi);

    } else if (!(rowId in columns.rowSale)) {
        // If id key doesn't exists in the array, add it
        result.rowSale.rowId = new Array();
        result.rowSale.rowId.push(rowNdi);

    } else if (!columns.rowSale.rowId.indexOf(rowNdi)) {
        // If ndi isn't in the array, add it
        result.rowSale.rowId.push(rowNdi);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I did'nt missunderstand you, this should do the trick:

```
function buildTree(input) {
    var output = {};
    for (var i in input) {
        var state = input[0];
        var id = input[1];
        var ndi = input[2];
        if (output[state] === undefined) output[state] = {};
        if (output[state][id] === undefined) output[state][id] = [];
        output[state][id].push(ndi);
    };
    return output;
};
```